# Explicit wait doesn't work with selenium python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I am learning selenum with python and the explicit wait method doesn't work to click on the 'accept cookies' button.
Otherwise, the time.sleep method work and I would like to understant why the explicit wait method doersn't work.
I typed this code : (sorry for my bad english, I'm french...)

```
driver.get("https://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/")
driver.maximize_window()

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "gdpr-consent-notice")))

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="save"]/span[1]/div/span'))).click()
```

Comment: Hello every one ! :)

Comment: What do mean by "doesn't work"? What are trying to achieve and what issue are going through?

Comment: To click to the accept cookies button we need to do a switch to frame before.  The problème is theWebDriverWait in the second assertion

The following code work :

Comment: `WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "gdpr-consent-notice")))`

Comment: `time.sleep(1)`

Comment: `WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="save"]/span[1]/div/span'))).click()`

Comment: The issue is the driver doesn't click on the accept button if I remove " time.sleep(1)"

Comment: it works as expected whats the issue u are facing

Comment: Normally we don't need to add the time.sleep in the code of my first message

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use the explicit wait?
Selenium by default has a timeout when you use findelement, that I think it's about 10 seconds.
If you want to know more about this issue, I found that website(blog).
https://blog.devgenius.io/browser-automation-with-python-and-selenium-5-waits-4b9e4636548c
or that other
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html